# UIPageViewController ans UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have several pages on `UIPageViewController`. Each page is created from its own view, that has nested views. One of them is image. I want to have contol made in the way, that user can change pages by swipe on everything but image. Swipe on image will change images and not the page.

How can I achieve this? I have added `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the image, set userInteraction to YES, but swipe is send through and cause page turn.

I have this code in view load method (awakeFromNib)

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeImageRight)];
[swipeGestureRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
swipeGestureRight.delegate = self;
swipeGestureRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.image addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRight];
```

Comment: Your swipe recognizer must 'scale the hierarchy'. This is, your imageview is a subview of the view from your controller, which hold a page controller swipe. You must tell that swipe(from the page controller) to only respond after your own fails.
Search for require gesture recognizer to fail.

Comment: try this sample for some reference https://github.com/jackhumphries/UIPageViewController-PDF

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should do the trick for you :

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    if (gestureRecognizer == self){
        if ([otherGestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:self.class]){
            if ([self isGestureRecognizerInSuperviewHierarchy:otherGestureRecognizer]){
                return YES;
            } else if ([self isGestureRecognizerInSiblings:otherGestureRecognizer]){
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL) isGestureRecognizerInSiblings:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    UIView *superview = self.view.superview;
    NSUInteger index = [superview.subviews indexOfObject:self.view];
    if (index != NSNotFound){
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
            UIView *sibling = superview.subviews[i];
            for (UIGestureRecognizer *viewRecognizer in sibling.gestureRecognizers){
                if (recognizer == viewRecognizer){
                    return YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
- (BOOL) isGestureRecognizerInSuperviewHierarchy:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if (!recognizer) return NO;
    if (!self.view) return NO;
    //Check siblings
    UIView *superview = self.view;
    while (YES) {
        superview = superview.superview;
        if (!superview) return NO;
        for (UIGestureRecognizer *viewRecognizer in superview.gestureRecognizers){
            if (recognizer == viewRecognizer){
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    if ([gestureRecognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:)]){
        return [(id <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)gestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:otherGestureRecognizer];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: It is not working.. otherGestureRecognizer is never set to UIPageViewController gesture.